# how to get unique list of years from json data?

Tags: javascript

I have following json data and want to get an array of only `financial_year`. It has to be only unique years.

```
var data = [{"financial_year": 2017, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}, {"financial_year": 2017, "revenue": 3000, "costs": 2000}, {"financial_year": 2016, "revenue": 1000, "costs": 500},{"financial_year": 2016, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}, {"financial_year": 2015, "revenue": 5000, "costs": 3000}, {"financial_year": 2015, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}]
```

I want to get an array with a list of only years. My expected output is:

```
[2017, 2016, 2015]
```

I tried to fo following:

```
var years = []
data.forEach((val, index) => {
    years.push(val.financial_year)
});

var lis_of_years = Array.from(new Set(years))
```

But for some weird reason, I'm getting two arrays when I `console.log(lis_of_years)`. Could you please check what am  I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code is working as expected.

Comment: I can see only one console.log - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vjZqJb?editors=1010 and your code looks fine

Comment: From the answers below, one line: `const years = [...new Set(data.map(({ financial_year }) => financial_year))];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ES6 `Set` class to get the unique values.

`[... new Set(data.map(a=>a.financial_year))]`

```js
var data = [{"financial_year": 2017, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}, {"financial_year": 2017, "revenue": 3000, "costs": 2000}, {"financial_year": 2016, "revenue": 1000, "costs": 500},{"financial_year": 2016, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}, {"financial_year": 2015, "revenue": 5000, "costs": 3000}, {"financial_year": 2015, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}]

console.log([... new Set(data.map(a=>a.financial_year))])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const years = data.map(obj => obj.financial_year)
const uniqueYears = [...new Set(years)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're not checking for duplicates. You can map the objects to an array of years, then turn it into a Set and back:

```js
const input = [{
  "financial_year": 2017,
  "revenue": 2000,
  "costs": 1000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2017,
  "revenue": 3000,
  "costs": 2000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2016,
  "revenue": 1000,
  "costs": 500
}, {
  "financial_year": 2016,
  "revenue": 2000,
  "costs": 1000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2015,
  "revenue": 5000,
  "costs": 3000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2015,
  "revenue": 2000,
  "costs": 1000
}];
const years = input.map(({ financial_year }) => financial_year);
const dedupedYears = [...new Set(years)];
console.log(dedupedYears);
```

Another method would be to `reduce` into a set directly:

```js
const input = [{
  "financial_year": 2017,
  "revenue": 2000,
  "costs": 1000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2017,
  "revenue": 3000,
  "costs": 2000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2016,
  "revenue": 1000,
  "costs": 500
}, {
  "financial_year": 2016,
  "revenue": 2000,
  "costs": 1000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2015,
  "revenue": 5000,
  "costs": 3000
}, {
  "financial_year": 2015,
  "revenue": 2000,
  "costs": 1000
}];
const yearsSet = input.reduce((accum, { financial_year }) => accum.add(financial_year), new Set());
const dedupedYears = [...yearsSet];
console.log(dedupedYears);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the values as value for making a set and take the values of it.

```js
var data = [{ financial_year: 2017, revenue: 2000, costs: 1000 }, { financial_year: 2017, revenue: 3000, costs: 2000 }, { financial_year: 2016, revenue: 1000, costs: 500 }, { financial_year: 2016, revenue: 2000, costs: 1000 }, { financial_year: 2015, revenue: 5000, costs: 3000 }, { financial_year: 2015, revenue: 2000, costs: 1000 }],
    years = Array.from(new Set(data.map(({ financial_year }) => financial_year)));

console.log(years);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result , use below option of using map and filter

1. map to get array of years
2. filter to get unique values of years

   ```
    var lis_of_years = data.map(val => val.financial_year)
                     .filter((v, i, self) => self.indexOf(v) === i)
   ```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gzxNQN?editors=1010

```js
var data = [{"financial_year": 2017, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}, {"financial_year": 2017, "revenue": 3000, "costs": 2000}, {"financial_year": 2016, "revenue": 1000, "costs": 500},{"financial_year": 2016, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}, {"financial_year": 2015, "revenue": 5000, "costs": 3000}, {"financial_year": 2015, "revenue": 2000, "costs": 1000}]



var lis_of_years = data.map(val => val.financial_year)
                       .filter((v, i, self) => self.indexOf(v) === i)

console.log(lis_of_years)
```